# Confusion regarding calculation of effective mass tensor

Tags: solid-state-physics, mass

I want to calculate the effective mass tensor as has been done in this [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jz500480m). The authors go about calculating the effective mass in [100],[010] and [001] for a few different compounds, by curve fitting on electronic band structures diagram. This question will be an extension(let me know if I am violating the stack's policy on cross posting or anything, but the questions are a bit different) of a [question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9566/how-does-one-decide-the-directions-in-which-they-will-calculate-effective-mass/9578?noredirect=1#comment20000_9578) I posted on Matter Modeling stack exchange.

The post actually got an amazing answer which talked about first determining the effective mass tensor and then actually finding the eigen vectors which would correspond to the fundamental direction of effective mass. This is different from what has been done in the paper I have linked above but makes more sense. So is the paper wrong??

Comment: It isn't wrong, they are just calculating something different.

Comment: @JonCuster So the way I understand it is that if you calculate the effective mass along the eigenvectors direction and lets say you apply some external field to your crystal in that particular direction so you observe the phenomena according to that mass because electron moves in that direction only. But if the off diagonal elements are not zero then even if you apply field in a particular direction electron could move in some other direction making the calculating the effective mass in that particular direction not useful. So what could be the use case they are going for??